# Want to access a setting in webconfig's appsetting section inside a custom control's attribute

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that I declare like:

```
<hello:someControl id="asdf" />
```

Now I need to access a config setting in the web.config's appsetting and give access to it to the control.

I want to pass this value using the attribute.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried accessing the configuration setting from the control's code behind?

```
string mySetting = "";
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"] != null)
     mySetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"].ToString();
```